# Google App Engine: Upload data syntax?

Tags: google-app-engine, syntax, upload

I'm trying to use `appcfg.py` to upload to localhost/Google App Engine. I've basically been following these [instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) word for word, but now I'm having trouble.

Here is the command I'm trying:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --app-id=appname --config_file="path\to\ItemLoader.py" --filename="path\to\data.csv" --kind=Item --url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api <path\to\app>
```

I get back:

```
The syntax of this command is incorrect.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Looks like I'm not actually supposed to include the < > chars around the path to the app. Now I'm getting an error:

```
appcfg.py: error: no such option: --app-id
```

**UPDATE 2:** I took out the `--app-id` parameter, and now another error:

```
appcfg.py: error: Expected <directory> argument
```

So... I do need the brackets?

**UPDATE 3:** Ok, it accepts the commands with quotes instead of brackets. But the development console at `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore` shows that the Datastore is still empty. The following error was reported:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: `path\\to\\google\\SDK\\bulkloader-log-20100301.200921'
```

**UPDATE 4:** It appears that it was a permissions error with my file system. I granted a bunch of permissions, and now it is complaining about the referenced scripts instead.

Comment: Just to make sure: you replaced "<path\to\app>" with the actual path, yes?

Comment: http://groups.google.co.in/group/google-appengine

Comment: @redtuna yes, but it's just a directory path in brackets. I am suspicious of this part. What exactly is the directory this is supposed to be pointing to? The one where app.yaml can be found?

Comment: you are uploading rather than downloading, so how will your local datastore get populated?

Comment: @nvl I'm uploading to localhost. That works, right? Or is there some other way for me to populate the local datastore?

Comment: Another shot in the dark: @Rosarch, you say you still have the brackets there; try without them.

Comment: I got it to work eventually. (See update #4). Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

> appcfg.py upload_data --app-id=appname
>   --config_file="path\to\ItemLoader.py" --filename="path\to\data.csv" --kind=Item --url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api

by :

> appcfg.py upload_data
>   **--application**=appname --config_file="path\to\ItemLoader.py" --filename="path\to\data.csv" --kind=Item --url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api